# Get specific column from JSON file in Angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular6

right now I am working on an Angular2 project when I have to use an online JSON file. I used `http.get` but I get all the file and I want only the second, and third column, first_name and last_name.

Here is the JSON file > http://alexgr.ro/ehealth/patients.json

and here is my code

**admin1.component.ts where I want to show the dates**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'admin1',
templateUrl: `admin1.component.html`,
})
export class Admin1Component  {
enable: boolean;
_profile: {}

constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    this.enable = false;
}

loadUser() {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(data => this._profile = data);
    this.enable = true;
 }
}
```

**my user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor (private http: Http) {}

 getUser() {
 return this.http.get('http://alexgr.ro/ehealth/patients.json')
  .map((res:Response) => res.json());
 }
}
```

**and my admin1.component.html**

```
<div>
<button (click)="loadUser()">Load User</button>
<div *ngIf="enable">
    {{ _profile | json }}
</div>
```

Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ngFor to loop over the items,

```
<div>
<button (click)="loadUser()">Load User</button>
<div *ngIf="enable">
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let pro of _profile ">
       <h1> {{ pro.first_name}} </h1>
       <h1> {{ pro.last_name}} </h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over the array like this -

```
<div *ngFor='let profile of _profile'>
    {{ profile.first_name }}     {{ profile.last_name }}
</div>
```

Currently, you are using `json` pipe which just prints whole data as it is into DOM.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
<button (click)="loadUser()">Load User</button>
<div *ngIf="enable">
<div *ngFor="let profile of _profile  "
    {{ profile | json }}
</div>
```

In addition to the answers above, you can still use the `Json pipe` with `ngFor`.